# How to find if a string appears anywhere in an object?

Tags: javascript, loops, object, search, find

I have several objects.  They are structured many different ways.  For example:

```
var obj1 = {
  'key1':'value',
  'key2':[{
     'somekey':'somevalue',
     'nestedObject': [{
        'something':'{{THIS STRING}}'
      }]
   }]
 }

var obj2 = {
      'key5':'some text {{THIS STRING}} some more text',
      'name':[{
         'somekey':'somevalue'
       }]
     }
```

There are many more objects than this, and their structures can be infinitely different.

I am looking for a way to find **{{THIS STRING}}**, no matter where it appears in the object, and no matter what other text surrounds it.  All I need to know is a true/false of if it appears anywhere at all in the values of any given object, regardless of how deeply-nested in the object it is.

Thank you!

Comment: Also post what you tried.

Comment: i mean... if it's a simple object (only contains objects/arrays/primitives, no self referencing) json.stringify should be easy. but you haven't really told us anything about the object structure or what it may contain.

Comment: simple tree walker

Comment: It should be a simple recursive function. Loop over all the properties. If it's a string, return true if it contains the search string. If it's an object, call the function recursively, and return `true` if it returns true. If you get to the end of the loop, return false.

Answer (score 1):

**Note: This is a quick method indeed, but it does not work for all use cases. e.g. if your keys may contain the desired string, this will give wrong output. See comments below.**

Not the cleanest of solutions, but you can turn your object into a JSON string using `JSON.stringify()`, and then look for the string you want inside that string.

```
var obj1_str = JSON.stringify(obj1);
var isInFile = obj1_str.includes("your_string"); //true if your string is there, false otherwise.
```

Comment: This will also find the string in the keys, not just the values.

Comment: It also won't work if the string contains any characters that require escaping in JSON.

Comment: Well, I know this will not work in all conditions. But if the OP has a very specific use case (e.g. if their string is not present as a key), this could be a quick way to do it. Not clean, but quick.

Comment: In my specific case, the string will always be in a value (never a key), and will always be a string surrounded by {{ }}  (so, "{{some string}}", for example)